# Why it comes "-" mark in front to the answer in my C code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a=1;
int b=2;
unsigned int temp1,temp2,n,sum;

int find_nth_term(int N, int a, int b) {
    if(N==1)
        return a;
    else if(N==2)
        return b;
    else{
        temp1=2;
        temp2=1;
        n=3;
        while(n<=N){
            sum=(2*temp1)+(3*temp2);
            temp2=temp1;
            temp1=sum;
            n++;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

int main() {
    int N;

    if(N>=1 && N<=10000){
        scanf("%d", &N);
        int ans = find_nth_term(N, a, b);

        printf("%d", ans); 
    }
    else
        exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

this is my program and when I enter a value over 104 the answer contains `-` mark in front of them?

i write this code to find the Nth value of the sequence 1 2 7 20 61 ......

Comment: You do not initialize N before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum for your int is 2,147,483,647. At 104 your find_nth_term becomes larger than the maximum. This causes errors (like @Asteroids With Wings says).

You can fix it by using `long long int` and print it by `%lld`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a=1;
int b=2;
unsigned int temp1,temp2,n,sum;

long long int find_nth_term(int N, int a, int b) {
    if(N==1)
        return a;
    else if(N==2)
        return b;
    else{
        temp1=2;
        temp2=1;
        n=3;
        while(n<=N){
            sum=(2*temp1)+(3*temp2);
            temp2=temp1;
            temp1=sum;
            n++;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

int main() {
    int N = 104;

    if(N>=1 && N<=10000){
        long long int ans = find_nth_term(N, a, b);

        printf("%lld", ans); 
    }
    else
        exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

You'll see the output 2,754,580,808 which is higher than 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 1):

Because they're *negative*.

Less than zero.

Like "minus five", or "minus three hundred and fifty two".

When your numbers get so large that they exceed the maximum value of an `int`, they "overflow". A program with integer overflow has undefined behaviour. One possible symptom of this is that you get a bad, negative value out of it.

Use a datatype large enough for your values.

---

Also, you have `scanf("%d", &N);` in the wrong place. It should be *before* you query `N` for its value, not after.

Comment: You could also warn that overflow of a signed type is UB in C and while you can expect overflow in most cases you can also get saturation or some other behavior.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I tried to put that across with my "one possible symptom", and was hoping that giving the term "overflow" in quotes would serve as a springboard for OP research, but you're absolutely right that should be clearer. I'll make an edit :)